# Determine the indefinite integral for $x\tan^{-1}x^{2}$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I'm not sure how to move on after using integration by parts to arrive at

$$\frac{x^{2}\tan^{-1}x^{2}}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{x^{2}}{x^{4} + 1}\,dx$$

Comment: So... You want to know how to integrate $\frac{x^2}{x^4+1}$, don't you?

Comment: You let $x^4 = u^2$ so you'll get $\int \frac{u}{u^2+1} \, du$ then you'll assign the denominator to another variable $v$ wherein $v' = 2u$.

Comment: The right-hand integral might be solvable with a trig substitution. Note that  $\tan^2(x) + 1 = \sec^2(x)$

Comment: @Aldon I found your comment to be the most useful. Thanks.

Comment: You did the integration by parts wrong. $dv=x dx$, $u=\arctan(x^2) dx$, $du=(2x)/(1+x^4)$, $v=x^2/2$. You should have gotten $x^2\arctan(x^2)/2-\int x^3/(1+x^4)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int x\arctan x^2\ dx=\frac{1}{2}x^2\arctan x^2 -\int \frac{x^3}{1+x^4}\ dx$$

by integration by parts, where u=arctan(x^2) and dv=xdx.

next use a simple u-substition where $u=1+x^4$.

$$\int \arctan x^2\ dx=\frac{1}{2} x^2 \arctan x^2-\int \frac{x^3}{1+x^4}\ dx
             =\frac{1}{2}x^2\arctan x^2 -\frac{1}{4}\ln(1+x^4)+C  $$
qed

Comment: Please learn how to write in Mathjax thanks.

Comment: Despite the format issue, this is actually the answer that's closest to OP's approach.

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$\int \arctan(x)\,dx = x\arctan x-\int \frac{x}{1+x^2}\,dx = x \arctan(x)-\frac{1}{2}\log(1+x^2) $$
we clearly have:
$$\int x\arctan(x^2)\,dx = \frac{x^2}{2}\arctan(x^2)-\frac{1}{4}\log(1+x^4).$$

Answer (score 1):

Do not integrate by parts immediately.
Firstly take x^2 = k
The x will vanish on substitution
Then integrate by parts.When integrating differentiate tan^-1 (x) and integrate 1

source:
engineering student

Comment: This is the best solution but I won't upvote until it is better presented.

Comment: @Nalin can you please describe this solution a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Don't integrate by parts right away. Note that $d(x^2)=2x\,dx$. Let $u = x^2$

$$ \int x\arctan x^2 dx = \frac{1}{2} \int\arctan u\,du$$

You can take it from here.